# Numpy slice by list

Tags: python, numpy

for example,I have a matrix like this

```
   mat = np.diag((1,1,1,1,1,1))
        print(mat)
        out:[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 1 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 1 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 1 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 1 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

I may need some slices that can be combination of any lines and columns.
if it is lines=[0,1,2] columns=[0,1,2],I could use:

```
mat[0:3,0:3]
```

If I need lines=[0,1,2,5] columns=[0,1,2,5],I write:

```
mat[[0,1,2,5],[0,1,2,5]]
```

I can only get:

```
out:[1 1 1 1]
```

But I wanna get a matrix of 4×4.By the way,the columns always equal lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-contiguous indices you can do:

```
mat[[0,1,2,5],:][:,[0,1,2,5]]
```

i.e. first get the specified rows (gets a 4x6 matrix out of it) then get the specified columns from that.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You can shorten it a bit `mat[idx][:, idx]`